# Table join using the repository pattern

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository

I am new to repository pattern. If I want to join two tables, where should I implement the logic? I have implemented it as shown below. Is there any better way to achieve the same?

This is my `UserRepository` class:

```
public class UserRepository : Repository<UserMaster>, IUserRepository
{
    public UserRepository(DbContext context)
        : base(context)
    {

    }
    public UserMaster GetById(int id)
    {
        return FindBy(x => x.Userid == id).FirstOrDefault();
    }

}
```

This is the Service layer from which I am implementing data access functions:

```
 public class UserService : EntityService<UserMaster>, IUserService
{
    IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    IUserRepository _userRepo;
    IRolePrivilegeMapRepository _rolePrevilegeMapRepo;
    IUserRoleMapRepository _userRoleMapRepo;

    public UserService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IUserRepository userRepo, IRolePrivilegeMapRepository rolePrevilegeMapRepo,IUserRoleMapRepository userRoleMapRepo)
        : base(unitOfWork, userRepo)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        _userRepo = userRepo;
        _rolePrevilegeMapRepo = rolePrevilegeMapRepo;
        _userRoleMapRepo = userRoleMapRepo;
    }

    public List<int> GetUserPrevileges(string UserName)
    {
        var rolePrevilegeMap = _rolePrevilegeMapRepo.GetAll();
        var userRoleMap = _userRoleMapRepo.GetAll();
        var userMaster = _userRepo.GetAll();

        var Privs = (from  rpm in rolePrevilegeMap
                     join urm in userRoleMap on rpm.RoleId equals urm.Roleid
                     join um in userMaster on urm.Userid equals um.Userid
                     where um.Username.Equals(UserName) && rpm.IsDeleted == false && urm.IsDeleted == false
                     select rpm.PrivilegedId).Distinct();

        if (Privs.Any())
        {
            return Privs.ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }

    }

}
```

I have injected `IRolePrivilegeMapRepository`, `IUserRoleMapRepository`, and `IUserRepository` using Autofac to the `UserService` class for joining the tables.

```
    var rolePrevilegeMap = _rolePrevilegeMapRepo.GetAll();
    var userRoleMap = _userRoleMapRepo.GetAll();
    var userMaster = _userRepo.GetAll();
```

**The `GetAll` method is of return type `IQueryable`**. After that, using that result, I have done the join. Is this the right way to approach? Or Is there any better way to implement the same?

Answer (score 2):

I don't do EF, so I am focusing on the code only. But nevertheless maybe this will help you in doing joins with EF: [how-to-join-multiple-tables-using-repository-pattern-entity-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20623694/2655508)

- Based on the [naming guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx) input parameters should be named using `camelCase` casing. So

  > ```
  > public List<int> GetUserPrevileges(string UserName)
  > ```

  should be

  ```
  public List<int> GetUserPrevileges(string userName)
  ```

  The same is true local varaiables like `Privs` but in addition you shouldn't shorten your varaiables names because you are reducing the readability of your code. So better use `privileges` instead of `Privs`.
- This `if..else`

  > ```
  > if (Privs.Any())
  > {
  >     return Privs.ToList();
  > }
  > else
  > {
  >     return null;
  > }
  > ```

  does not add real value. Why do you want to return `null`? It would be much easier for the calling code if you return an empty `List` for the case that there aren't any privileges which match the requirement.

  If the `IQuerable<T>` doesn't contain any items, a call to `ToList()` will just create an empty list.

  If you use the returned `List<>` to just iterate over the items, you won't even need a check if it is empty.