# Returning IQueryable<T> from my repository in Repository pattern design pattern

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository, join

I am developing an application based on Repository design pattern. What should be the return type from the Repository?

This is my `UserRepository` class:

```
public class UserRepository : Repository<UserMaster>, IUserRepository
{
    public UserRepository(DbContext context)
        : base(context)
    {

    }
    public UserMaster GetById(int id)
    {
        return FindBy(x => x.Userid == id).FirstOrDefault();
    }

}
```

The base `Repository` class:

```
public abstract class Repository<T> : IRepository<T>
  where T : class
{
    protected DbContext _entities;
    protected readonly IDbSet<T> _dbset;

    public Repository(DbContext context)
    {
        _entities = context;
        _dbset = context.Set<T>();
    }

    public virtual IQueryable<T> GetAll()
    {

        return _dbset.AsQueryable<T>();
    }

    public IQueryable<T> FindBy(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {

        IQueryable<T> query = _dbset.Where(predicate).AsQueryable();
        return query;
    }

    public virtual T Add(T entity)
    {
        return _dbset.Add(entity);
    }

    public virtual T Delete(T entity)
    {
        return _dbset.Remove(entity);
    }

    public virtual void Edit(T entity)
    {
        _entities.Entry(entity).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public virtual void Save()
    {
        _entities.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Is this the right way to return `IQueryable` from the repository? If I want to join two tables, where should I implement the join logic? Inside or outside the repository?

Currently my return type is `IQueryable` from the Repository and I am doing join on the Business layer after calling `GetAll()` function (returns `IQueryable`) of the required tables. Is this the right approach?

Comment: `If i want to join two tables, where should i implement the join logic?` has [been asked before](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/95650/52915).

Comment: If you're getting a user by it's primary key ID, I'd expect you to call `.SingleOrDefault()` rather than `.FirstOrDefault()`.

Answer (score 2):

IQueryable is a leaky abstraction(you don't wan't to know anything about sql in the service layer).
It is also very difficult to test.

I would recommend not returning IQueryable.
I would return IEnumerable or ICollection and make my queries run in the repository(ToList on the repository).

I would create queries in my repositories to handle the joins.
You can test your queries separately for correctness and performance.